# Unable to connect to external services from App Engine development server with urlfetch or urllib2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urllib2, urlfetch

The following code works in the Python interactive shell:

```
import urllib2
result = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com/")
```

and gives a 200 result.

If I run the same code in an AppEngine app running locally with the development server, it fails with the following error:

```
URLError: <urlopen error An error occured while connecting to the server:
Unable to fetch  URL: http://www.google.com/ 
Error: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>`
```

I've tried using the `urlfetch` library directly:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
result = urlfetch.fetch("http://www.google.com")
```

and this also fails (which makes sense, as I believe `urllib2` within AppEngine calls `URLFetch` internally?)

I can clearly access the URL from my local machine - so what's happening?

UPDATE: the relevant stack trace:

```
File "c:\dev\repos\stackoverflow\main.py", line 40, in get_latest_comments
result = urlfetch.fetch("http://www.google.com")

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\urlfetch.py", line 266, in fetch
return rpc.get_result()

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 604, in get_result
return self.__get_result_hook(self)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\urlfetch.py", line 397, in _get_fetch_result
raise DownloadError("Unable to fetch URL: " + url + error_detail)

DownloadError: Unable to fetch URL: http://www.google.com Error: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: did you read the threads on google groups there seems to be a couple people with same issue http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7668

Comment: In there a firewall/proxy involved in your connection?

Comment: @dm03514 - yes, I have - but there seems to be no definitive answer.

Comment: I've been having the same problem.  any solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

DO you have a proxy configured with environment variables?  The dev_appserver clears all env vars.

Comment: I don't have a proxy configured locally, no, but that doesn't mean that we don't have some strange internal office configuration that is causing a problem. I will continue to investigate. (Thx for the tip on the env vars - didn't know that.)